# MouseExited on JPanel runs when JButton in panel hovered over?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

I have a JPanel (let's call it ctrlPanel), and using null layout I have placed an JLabel in the background of it. On top of this label I have another JLabel and a JButton (by default hidden). I'd like to show that label and button when the user hovers over ctrlPanel with their mouse.

It works (almost) fine by adding a mouseAdapter to ctrlPanel, and calling showControls() when mouseEntered and hideControls() when mouseExited. These use setVisible to show/hide the components on top.

However, when the user hovers over the JButton, ctrlPanel seems to get an mouseExited call and this makes the JButton "flicker" (mouseExited->mouseEntered->mouseExited and so on). Which doesn't make sense to me, because the JButton is *in* ctrlPanel. I mean, there's no problem when hovering over the JLabel.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For the sake of sanity, avoid null layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is doable - internal controls intercept mouse events. So you can either

- create a mouse listener and attach it to panel, buttons, etc, and handle the stuff properly everywhere
- check the coordinate at mouseExited(), and if the mouse is still inside the panel, ignore that event

Answer (score 1):

What I did to deal with this problem and as in ixula's answer:

> "check the coordinate at mouseExited(), and if the mouse is still inside the panel, ignore that event"

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if(stillInPanel(e.getPoint())) return;
    // Exit logic
}

private boolean stillInPanel(Point2D p) {
    return (YOURJPANEL.contains((Point)p));
}
```

Where YOURJPANEL can be any container.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this too, and was surprised to find the same results.  I guess Java's components don't handle mouse-in and mouse-out events in the same way as JavaScript and HTML does (via event bubbling).  Using a different layout manager didn't have any effect.

I think this is the safest way to handle the issue: create a custom `JPanel` class the overrides the `add()` methods.  This delegates to `super.add()` but also adds its custom mouse listener to each component that gets passed in.  This way, you will still get the mouse-entered and mouse-exited events but you will be able to keep track of elements inside the panel.  Whatever you do when the mouse exits the panel will only take effect very briefly and will be undone immediately when the next event fires.  You shouldn't see any visible change to the GUI, but if you see a flicker, try making your window double-buffered.